# How to open pdf from url online in Android without download option?

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview

In my app I want the user to read the pdf files inside my app without any option to download them. How can I do this? I am using the following code but not working-

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?"+pdf_url);
```

Is there any other way to do this? If you can do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can open pdf from URL online in Android without a download option.

**Kotlin**

```
val path="https://github.github.com/training-kit/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf"
    
activityWebViewBinding.webview.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
activityWebViewBinding.webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
val url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=$path"
activityWebViewBinding.webview.loadUrl(url)
```

**Java**

```
 String path="https://github.github.com/training-kit/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf";
        
 webview.settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
 webview.settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 String url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+path;
 webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Can I get the Java Version?

Comment: Error 404. The requested url was not found on the server?

Comment: I am loading from Firebase.

Comment: please try once `webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="+url);`

Comment: if this is not working than user PDFViiweer https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: Above link won't work anymore use this link: https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=yourUrl

Comment: Is there any limitation from google for using these links `https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=$path` `docs.google.com/viewer?url=yourUrl` `https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+path`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply launch intent as below

```
val pdfUrl = "ENTER_PDF_URL_HERE"
val intent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdfUrl))
    .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
context.startActivity(intent)
```

This would simply open it up device's pdf viewer app which comes in almost all android devices **com.google.android.apps.docs**

You can also safeguard this code by querying packages beforehand and adding fallbacks